# How to avoid redundant module naming for Single struct modules in rust?

Tags: rust, module

Maybe this just bothers me, but in certain cases I'd like to have one struct per module file.

Let's say I have a struct named **User** like this:

```
struct User {
    name: String
}
```

And let's say I have a file structure like where the User struct code is located in **src/models/user.rs** like this:

```
src/
    models/
           user.rs
```

And now I'd like to be able to use the User struct like this:

```
use crate::models::User;
```

Of course that's not possible. Instead it needs to be referred with:

```
use crate::models::user::User;
```

To me this looks quite ugly and I consider it redundant if both words, **user** *and* **User**, are part of the module path.

Is there any solution that doesn't seem to be as "clumsy" as the one just described?

It might as well be the case that I missed something regarding how the rust module naming system works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can [re-export](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-04-bringing-paths-into-scope-with-the-use-keyword.html#re-exporting-names-with-pub-use) the `User` struct in the `models` module with `pub use user::User;` and optionally make the `user` submodule private (so that no one outside of `models` can access it). Externally, the `User` struct can then be referred to as a member of the `models` module with `crate::models::User`.

See also:

- [*The Rust Reference: `use` Visibility*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/use-declarations.html#use-visibility)

Comment: I asked in the Rust chat about this solution because I was skeptical, and they told me this is very common practice.